# Vuejs - Can I use an imported function in my global router.beforeEach

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to use an imported function in my global router guard. But I'm getting this error:
`getCurrentStage is not defined`

`getCurrentStage` is imported from `shops.js`

`shop.js` looks like this

```
import axios from 'axios'

export function getCurrentStage() {
    axios.get("/admin/wine_app/shops").then(response => {
      return response.data.current_stage;
    });
}

export default getCurrentStage
```

I then import it like this: `import getCurrentStage from '../api/shops'`

And then try and use it like this in my global router guard:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if(to.name == null){
    let current_stage = getCurrentStage();
  }
  else {
    next();
  }
})
```

But I get the not defined error. Any help?

Comment: Is it `shop.js` or `shops.js`?  You used both

Comment: @Dan thanks.. its `shops.js` I've fixed it in the question

Comment: Are you exporting the function twice?

Comment: The error message `x is not defined` usually means that the identifier `x` hasn't been declared at all in the current scope. It isn't the same as having the value `undefined`, it's more extreme than that. The code presented in the question should work fine. I ran it myself without problems. Could you confirm that the line where you do the `import` is in the same file as the your router guard? If it is then my best guess would be a caching problem. Add some console logging to both files to confirm you aren't getting old copies of those files.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't returned anything in the exported function.  You need to return the axios promise so that `current_stage` has something returned to it:

```
export function getCurrentStage() {
  return axios.get("/admin/wine_app/shops").then(response => {
    return response.data.current_stage;
  });
}
```

That's just going to return the promise so you'll need to do some appropriate async stuff like `await` or `.then` with that promise.  For example:

```
getCurrentStage().then(stage => {
  current_stage = stage;
});
```

You're also exporting the function twice which is probably not intentional.  You don't need the first `export` if you only plan to retrieve it by importing the default.